# How can be the `$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` error solved?

Tags: r, vector, glm, bayesian, brms

I'm trying to perform a CAPM regression analysis with a Bayesian GLM. I have developed the R code below but when I try to fit the model for the posterior predictive checks `posterior_intercept <- fitted(model_capm)$Estimate[1,]` I got `Error in fitted(model_capm)$Estimate:$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`.  I tried to convert the variable created `model_capm` to a dataframe as it has been created as a `Large brmsfit` but with no success.

Here is the code up to the error line:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(brms) 
library(bayesplot)

set.seed(42)
size <- 200
Rf <- 0.02
ERm <- 0.1
beta <- 1.5
sigma <- 0.05

ERm_samples <- rnorm(size, ERm, sigma)

epsilon <- rnorm(size, 0, sigma)
ERi_samples <- Rf + beta * (ERm_samples - Rf) + epsilon

market_excess_return <- ERm_samples - Rf
asset_excess_return <- ERi_samples - Rf

data_capm <- data.frame(market_excess_return=market_excess_return, asset_excess_return=asset_excess_return)

ggplot(data_capm, aes(x=market_excess_return, y=asset_excess_return)) +
  geom_point(aes(color='Sampled Data')) +
  labs(x='Market Excess Return', y='Asset Excess Return', title='Generated CAPM Data') +
  theme_minimal()

# Bayesian regression using brms
model_capm <- brm(asset_excess_return ~ market_excess_return, data = data_capm, 
                  family = gaussian(), prior = c(
                    prior(normal(0, 20), class = Intercept),
                    prior(normal(0, 20), class = b),
                    prior(cauchy(0, 10), class = sigma)
                  ))

# Plotting the trace
trace_capm <- as.mcmc(model_capm) 
bayesplot::mcmc_trace(trace_capm)

# Posterior predictive checks
posterior_intercept <- fitted(model_capm)$Estimate[1,]
posterior_slope <- fitted(model_capm)$Estimate[2,]

posterior_intercept <- fitted(model_capm)[1, "Estimate"]
posterior_slope <- fitted(model_capm)[2, "Estimate"]
```

Comment: `fitted(model_capm)` is a matrix, not a data frame, so I think you want `fitted(model_capm)[1,"Estimate"]` and `fitted(model_capm)[2,"Estimate"]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `class()` function to verify that your object is indeed a data frame. if it is not, you may want consider retrieving the data using indexing `[]`, or alternatively, try to convert the object to a data frame (or tibble, my preference, using `as_tibble()`).

```
fitted_ <- fitted(model_capm)
class(fitted_)
as_tibble(fitted_)
```

This should give you access to all the posterior distribution
again, you can always just access `model_capm[2]` etc..

Finaly, you can look at the structure of your model object by simply pressing on it through the environment. when you hover, on the right side you will see a button and if you click it, it will paste the way to call that object in the console
[image]

btw
When setting the color for your points, since you are not referring to a variable from your data frame, you may want to set the color **outside** of the `aes` function, and just declare the color explicitly. That way the legend doesn't appear for no reason:
`geom_point(color='tomato')`